# Padding Empty Field in Unix Join Operation

Tags: linux, unix, join

I have two files where I want to perform union operation
based on 1st column:

file1.txt

```
foo 1
bar 2
qux 3
```

file2.txt

```
foo x
qux y
boo z
```

The result I hope to get is like this:

```
foo  1 x
bar  2 -
qux  3 y
boo  - z
```

where the empty fields of column 1 is padded
with "-".

But why this join command doesn't work as I expected?

```
$ join -a1 -a2 -e"-" file1.txt file2.txt
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"Important: FILE1 and FILE2 must be sorted on the join fields." (from [this](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/join) online manpage).

This problem #1. Problem #2 is worse: option `-e` is badly documented -- only works in conjunction with `-o`, so for example:

```
$ join -a 1 -a 2 -e'-' -o '0,1.2,2.2' sfile1.txt sfile2.txt
bar 2 -
boo - z
foo 1 x
qux 3 y
```

where the `s` prefix name indicated files that I've `sort`ed beforehand.

Edit: `man join` explains the `-o` switch (so does the online manpage I point to above). It specifies the fields to output (1.2 means 2nd field from file 1, &c), or 0 to mean the join field, and is a comma-separated list. (I didn't remember the 0 value, actually, so had originally given a clumsier solution requiring awk post-processing, but the current solution is better... and no awk needed!).

Comment: @Alex: thanks so much. I don't understand the option "-o '1.1,2.1,1.2,2.2'". Where can I find info about that? Also if you don't mind the awk please?

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain the -o, but do look at `man awk`: as I did, to check my explanation, I was reminded of the 0 value for field number, which I've now used in the edited example and makes post-processing unneeded. But do remember to sort your files beforehand!-)

Comment: Thanks, especially, for the -e requires -o info. I incorrectly assumed -e would fabricate empty values, rather than simply changing what the string representation of the empty value is.

Comment: In many (most?) cases, `-o auto` also works. That's equivalent to -o'0,1.2,1.3,...,1.n,2.2,2.3,...,2.m', where n is the number of fields in file 1 and m is the number of fields in file 2.

Answer (score 4):

-e only works with -o

```
join -a 1 -a 2 -e"-" -o auto file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: This `-o auto` does not work for me as the accepted answer.