# match values in first column of two files and join the matching lines in a new file

Tags: bash, awk, grep, match

I need to find matches with the string in column 1 ($1) in file1.txt with the string in column 1 ($1) in file2.txt. Then I want to join the lines where there was a match in a new file.

```
cat file1.txt
1050008 5.156725968 8.404038296 124.9198605 3.23E-21    2.33E-17    38.57865782
3310747 5.631470026 8.581936875 124.6039122 3.34E-21    2.33E-17    38.55204806
5910451 4.900364671 8.455329195 124.5720603 3.35E-21    2.33E-17    38.54935989
730156  5.565210738 8.48792701  122.2168789 4.28E-21    2.33E-17    38.34773989

cat file2.txt
4230037 ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00071  ILMN_333646 ERCC-00071  ERCC-00071
1050008 ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00009  ILMN_333584 ERCC-00009  ERCC-00009
5260356 ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00053  ILMN_333628 ERCC-00053  ERCC-00053
3310747 ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00144  ILMN_333719 ERCC-00144  ERCC-00144
5910451 ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00003  ILMN_333578 ERCC-00003  ERCC-00003
1710435 ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00138  ILMN_333713 ERCC-00138  ERCC-00138
1400612 ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00084  ILMN_333659 ERCC-00084  ERCC-00084
730156  ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00017  ILMN_333592 ERCC-00017  ERCC-00017
```

I would like the output file to look like this:

```
out.txt
1050008 5.156725968 8.404038296 124.9198605 3.23E-21    2.33E-17    38.57865782 1050008 ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00009  ILMN_333584 ERCC-00009  ERCC-00009
3310747 5.631470026 8.581936875 124.6039122 3.34E-21    2.33E-17    38.55204806 3310747 ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00144  ILMN_333719 ERCC-00144  ERCC-00144
5910451 4.900364671 8.455329195 124.5720603 3.35E-21    2.33E-17    38.54935989 5910451 ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00003  ILMN_333578 ERCC-00003  ERCC-00003
730156  5.565210738 8.48792701  122.2168789 4.28E-21    2.33E-17    38.34773989 730156  ILMN Controls   ILMN_Controls   ERCC-00017  ILMN_333592 ERCC-00017  ERCC-00017
```

The files are tab delimited and have missing values in some columns.

There is 31 columns in file2.txt and >47000 lines and I'm trying to do this in bash (OSX)

If you have a solution I would greatly appreciate if you could briefly explainn the steps as I'm very new to this.

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html or here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/awk-one-liner-for-multi-column.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = "\t"
  }
NR == FNR {
  # while reading the 1st file
  # store its records in the array f
  f[$1] = $0
  next
  }
$1 in f {
  # when match is found
  # print all values
  print f[$1], $0
  }' file1 file2
```

Comment: +1 for a nice script. It would fail if a space appeared in the first column of either file, though, or if that field was missing in one of the rows and the OP did specifically say some fields are missing values so you should really use `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}...'` to be safe.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind the output being ordered by the first column then you can use this invocation of the [join](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?join) command:

```
join <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) >out.txt
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Is there an easy way to handle the case where some files are missing lines?

Comment: @IsaacTurner this approach should work if either file is missing lines, what troubles are you having?

Comment: @cmh I wanted to fill in missing values - I found the solution in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984986/padding-empty-field-in-unix-join-operation