# Joining several files based on first file

Tags: join, awk, paste

I am trying to join several files based on a column in a specific file, namely "file1"

file1, serves as an "anchor":

```
rs00001
rs00002
rs00003
rs00004
rs00005
```

file2:

```
rs00001 chr4:180168624 ANAPC4
rs00002 chr5:67819450   FABP2
rs00004 chr4:115169445  TBC1D1
rs00005 chr4:67815503   MAML3
```

file3:

```
rs00003 19.65   6   5   1
rs00004 17.23   5   4   1
rs00005 20.95   8   2   0
```

Desired output:

```
rs00001 chr4:180168624 ANAPC4   .   .   .   .
rs00002 chr5:67819450   FABP2   .   .   .   .
rs00003 .   .   19.65   6   5   1
rs00004 chr4:115169445  TBC1D1  17.23   5   4   1
rs00005 chr4:67815503   MAML3   20.95   8   2   0
```

Codes that I tried:

```
paste file1 file2 file3
```

But it only combines everything into one and did not based on the column in file1.

```
rs00001 rs00001 chr4:180168624 ANAPC4   rs00003 19.65   6   5   1
rs00002 rs00002 chr5:67819450   FABP2   rs00004 17.23   5   4   1
rs00003 rs00004 chr4:115169445  TBC1D1  rs00005 20.95   8   2   0
rs00004 rs00005 chr4:67815503   MAML3   
rs00005
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Padding Empty Field in Unix Join Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984986/padding-empty-field-in-unix-join-operation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` but you need to set a few options:

```
join -a1 -o1.1,2.2,2.3 -e "." <(sort test_1) <(sort test_2) > tmp_1
join -a1 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 -e "." <(sort tmp_1) <(sort test_3) > output
```

Explanation: Your example is in 3 files ('test_1' 'test_2' and 'test_3') so the first step is to combine test_1 and test_2 into a temporary file (tmp_1) using join. The `-a1` option is telling join to look at the first column in both files for 'matches', the `-o1.1,2.2,2.3` is telling join to print the first column of the first file (1.1), the second column of the second file (2.2) and the third column of the second file (2.3). The `-e "."` is telling join to fill in any blanks with a dot. The inputs need to be sorted, so `<(sort file)` is used to sort the contents before being joined. Next step is to join the temp file with the test_3 file. The options are the same, but different columns are printed.

Comment: Hi @jared_mamrot, thanks for the explanation. For the numbers in "2.2,2.3", I understand that 2 and 3 meant for displaying columns at 2 and 3 both. What if I have many other columns, and I need all of them instead of stating which columns?

Comment: You can try `-o auto` instead of specifying columns, but I don't know if it will solve your problem. In future, please provide a better example of the data you are working with.